# setting GUI's workspace as the currend workspace

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I am writing a GUI program with matlab and I would like to test my variables to see if they are properly imported and to test how to access to different parts of the variables imported so I want my variables to be shown in workspace window of Matlab desktop
the main trouble is if I write a common program in the mfile editor after running the program variables will be shown in workspace windows but about GUI programs its not true
And if I Save the workspace of my program from the path
File>Save Workspace As...
in MFile Editor and then I try to open this access file in desktop i encounter
***No variables created***
How can I accesss the workspace of my GUI?

Answer (score 1):

If it is just for inspection, the easiest way is to [use the debugger](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_env/brqxeeu-175.html): set a breakpoint in one of the GUI callbacks, execution of the code halts there, and allows you to inspect the workspace, among other things.

If you want the GUI to return data to the main workspace, you add the line `uiwait(hObject)` to the end of the opening function. Then, the callback to e.g. the OK-button should have a line `handles.Output=myData; guidata(hObject,handles);` to send the variable `myData` to the GUI output, followed by `uiresume(hObject)`. This way, you can call your GUI as `myData = myGUI;`, and `myData` in the base workspace will be filled with whatever data the OK-callback gives it once the OK-button is clicked.

Note: Functions assign outputs, not internal variables to the base workspace. So I guess what you describe as "functions in the editor" are actually scripts that access and modify the contents of the workspace from which they're called.